# Is it possible to have an app meant both for internal employees and external public in the App Store?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

This question is regarding Apple rejecting the latest build of our iOS app and trying to find the best way to appeal the rejection. Here is the background:

My company has an iOS app that is used by our sales staff (internal company employees) to manage their day to day pipeline while on the go. Since the app is a major competitive advantage in the specific industry, we also advertise it to attract new sales people to come work for us. In order to have them experience the tech, we ask them to download the app, login with temporary credentials tied to their personal email IDs and play around with dummy data inside the app. Since we need the app to be publicly available for these individuals, we have so far published the app on the public app store instead of an enterprise store. While Apple approved our initial build about a year back and all subsequent updates, it recently rejected our latest build citing that the app should be in an enterprise store since it is being used for internal employees. While that does make sense given their policies, we are in a bind since the app also is used heavily in the recruitment process and hence needs to be available publicly.

Has anyone come across a similar situation with Apple? It's not clear why Apple suddenly decided to reject the app after having approved it multiple times over the last year. Were you able to convince Apple to reconsider the rejection, or is it a fruitless exercise?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) This is something only the Apple (specifically the App Store Review team) can answer. What reasons did they cite? What is the reason/specific guideline that Apple is citing to "not" allow it on the public App Store? What is stopping you to publish the same app separately as is or with recommended tweaks on the public App Store.

Answer (score 2):

You could reply to Apple stating that the app actually is not used exclusively by internal employees - but rather is made available publicly for marketing/recruiting purposes. I have often seen that Apple's initial request for further information and clarification results in them approving the app update afterall.

However, if you are forced to switch to the enterprise model - don't worry at all. You can still offer access to potential employees. You would then just host the app on your own web site (or any web site you have lying around really) - and just send the potential employee a link to install the app.

Answer (score 0):

It’s likely the person who was reviewing your app didn’t understand the specifics and made a snap judgement to reject the app. This happens. Make an appeal, given your app has been greenlighted for a year, this should be straight-forward. If it gets rejected again, speak to Apple and just explain the situation in plain English and ask to reconsider.